# Representing methods in have_* options in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, rspec

I created a method within an rb file in my spec folder. I want to use the method in checking if one of my elements has the returned value of the method as it's text. My question is, how would I write the method `name` into the have_selector text option?

My rspec file

```
def name
  user = User.first
  return user.name
end

describe "test" do

  it "has the name in the file"
    visit users_path
    page.should have_selector('td', text: name)
    # I need name in the text options to represent the method name created
  end

end
```

When I run rspec, it tells me that

```
NoMethodError: private method 'name' called for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Seems that you already "wrote the method `name`"  and put it into the matcher. Does that not do what you want?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. When I run rspec it tells me that `NoMethodError: private method 'name' called for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Did you populate the test database? Does `User.first` return a user?

Comment: Yep, the database is populated. I checked on Rails Console. I even ran the method through it and tested it.

Comment: Rails console in test environment or development? Your spec does not have any factories, so unless you're loading from fixtures, there won't be anything in the users table.

Comment: Expect stupid questions from me, but how would I tell Rails console to switch between test and development?

Comment: Got it to work. Post your answer suggesting to populate test database and I'll give you credit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.first`

returns `nil` unless you've added a row to the `users` table in the test database. You can do this with factories, fixtures, or just hand-rolling your own `User.create` in a before block.